# How to properly load .eot and .woff files with Babel?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, babeljs

Trying to run my project and getting the following error (`You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`) for `.eot`, `.woff`, `.ttf`, and `.svg` files:

```
ERROR in ./src/styles/fonts/nm/icons/nm-icons.svg?aaf8685e87a6901c76c52d0018389547
Module parse failed: C:\BaseProject\src\styles\fonts\nm\icons\nm-icons.svg?aaf8685e87a6901c76c52d0018389547 Unexpected t
oken (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:0)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprAtom (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1822:12)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprSubscripts (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1715:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeUnary (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1692:19)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExprOps (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1637:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeConditional (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1620:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseMaybeAssign (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1597:21)
    at Parser.pp$3.parseExpression (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1573:21)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:727:47)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (C:\BaseProject\node_modules\webpack-core\lib\NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
 @ ./~/css-loader?sourceMap!./src/styles/main.min.css 6:42409-42482
```

There are three other errors like the above for the other file types.

Here are my files:

**webpack.config.dev.js:**

```
import webpack from 'webpack';
import path from 'path';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
export default {
  debug: true,
  devtool: 'cheap-module-eval-source-map', // more info:https://webpack.github.io/docs/build-performance.html#sourcemaps and https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
  noInfo: true, // set to false to see a list of every file being bundled.
  entry: [
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?reload=true',
    'babel-polyfill',
    './src/index'
  ],
  target: 'web', // necessary per https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html#compile-and-test
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/src`, // Note: Physical files are only output by the production build task `npm run build`.
    publicPath: 'http://localhost:3000/', // Use absolute paths to avoid the way that URLs are resolved by Chrome when they're parsed from a dynamically loaded CSS blob. Note: Only necessary in Dev.
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'), // Tells React to build in either dev or prod modes. https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html (See bottom)
      __DEV__: true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({     // Create HTML file that includes references to bundled CSS and JS.
      template: 'src/index.ejs',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true
      },
      inject: true
    })
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
      {test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      {test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"},
      {test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
      {test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+.\d+.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
      {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loaders: ['file']},
      {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'},
      {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap']},
      {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']},
      {test: /\.less$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'less?sourceMap']}
    ]
  }
};
```

**.babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-1"
  ],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "presets": [
        "react-hmre"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**package.json: (removed some irrelevant dependencies)**

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "node tools/nodeVersionCheck.js",
    "setup": "node tools/setup/setupMessage.js && npm install && node tools/setup/setup.js",
    "start-message": "babel-node tools/startMessage.js",
    "prestart": "npm-run-all --parallel start-message remove-dist",
    "start": "npm-run-all --parallel test:watch open:src lint:watch",
    "open:src": "babel-node tools/srcServer.js",
    "open:dist": "babel-node tools/distServer.js",
    "clean-dist": "npm run remove-dist && mkdir dist",
    "remove-dist": "rimraf ./dist",
    "prebuild": "npm run clean-dist && npm run lint && npm run test",
    "build": "babel-node tools/build.js && npm run open:dist",
    "open:cover": "npm run test:cover && open coverage/index.html"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "6.10.1",
    "babel-core": "6.10.4",
    "babel-loader": "6.2.4",
    "babel-plugin-react-display-name": "2.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.13.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.11.1",
    "babel-preset-react-hmre": "1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "6.5.0",
    "babel-register": "6.9.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "0.9.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.22.0",
    "less": "2.7.1",
    "less-loader": "2.2.3",
    "node-sass": "3.8.0",
    "npm-run-all": "2.3.0",
    "open": "0.0.5",
    "replace": "0.3.0",
    "sass-loader": "4.0.0",
    "style-loader": "0.13.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.7",
    "webpack": "1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.6.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.12.1",
  }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include the error message as text, rather than a barely-readable red-on-blue picture of an error message. Not only is it more legible, but search engines can index the message, allowing more people to be helped by the question.

Comment: I placed the message in the question as you requested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the solution - I replaced my `eot`, `woff`, `ttf`, and `svg` loaders with the following line:

```
  {test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|svg|ttf)([\?]?.*)$/, loader: "file-loader"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configured test expressions don't match the resources you're trying to load. Try with something simpler:

```
loaders: [
  {test: /\.js$/, include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'), loaders: ['babel']},
  {test: /\.eot(\?[0-9a-z\-=]+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
  {test: /\.woff(2)(\?[0-9a-z\-=]+)?$/, loader: "url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff"},
  {test: /\.ttf(\?[0-9a-z\-=]+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
  {test: /\.svg(\?[0-9a-z\-=]+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'},
  {test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loaders: ['file']},
  {test: /\.ico$/, loader: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]'},
  {test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap']},
  {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'sass?sourceMap']},
  {test: /\.less$/, loaders: ['style', 'css?sourceMap', 'less?sourceMap']}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  When I tried your code, I ended up receiving more errors than I had originally.

Comment: I've updated the expressions, give it another go. Otherwise, everything else seems to be in order in your setup.

Comment: Just tried your updated expressions - still ~eleven of the `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.` errors.  Most of which are errors with `.woff` files, and then one error each for `.svg`, `.eot`, and `.ttf`.